# Телеграм бот на телебот оплата

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу тг бота на `python` с использованием `telebot`.
Нужно сделать оплату, вот код:

```py
elif(message.text == "buy"):
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        "Buy", 
        parse_mode='Markdown')
    bot.send_invoice(
        message.chat.id, 
        title="title", 
        description="desc", 
        provider_token=provider_token,
        invoice_payload="HAPPY FRIDAY", 
        currency="usd", 
        prices=prices, 
        is_flexible=False, 
        start_parameter='time-machine-example')
```

Выдает, вот это:

> A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400.
> Description: Bad Request: PAYMENT_PROVIDER_INVALID

В чем тут проблема?

Comment: Очень подозреваю что в ```provider_token```

Comment: Вы решили данную озвученную Вами проблему??? столкнулся один-в-один и ничего не могу сделать......